# are event.target.value and value attribute of input element the same in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';


function MyForm() {
  [state, setState]=useState("");
  
  return (
    <form>
      <label>Enter your name:
        <input type="text" 
               value={state}
               onChange={(event)=>setState(event.target.value)}  
         />
      </label>
    </form>
  )
}
```

When I do two-way binding in react I don't really understand how it works.
As I know, event.target is a property of an event object that refers to the element that triggered the event. So in this case, if we type something in input field, it will trigger the "onChange" which in turn sets the state to the value of element that triggered this change action (input element) and whilst its value is empty string(because its value attribute is equal to the state). So actually state setter function would have set the state to the current state that makes state and also value attribute always to be the same. But off course, I miss something here. Thanks in advance for any explanation.

Comment: React doesn’t have 2 way binding you have to build it yourself

Comment: React uses a virtual DOM, which it then diffs against the actual DOM to know what updates it needs to make. When you type into an input[type=text] you are typing into a DOM element. When you type into your input the DOM element value will update, the event will trigger, your onChange handler will be called setting the React state to the value in the DOM, React will then rerender updating it's virtual DOM diffing it against the actual and running all required updates. TLDR: `event.target.value != state`

Comment: React does not have two-way binding out of the box. It offers one-way binding. The event handler is you achieving two-way binding yourself.

Comment: @JacobSmit Thanks! I think it makes sense to me now  but I got two questions: 1. Do you mean virtual DOM element when you say- "When you type into an input[type=text] you are typing into a DOM element "  2. So does it also mean that event.target.value != value attribute of the element ?

Comment: When you are interacting with an element you are interacting with it's actual DOM representation. React will keep the actual DOM inline with it's virtual DOM, this diff/update generally happens after each react render cycle. So typing in the text box you change the value of the actual DOM, The event handler registered via React updates the state triggering a re-render which will then diff/update the actual DOM, although in this case since nothing else reacts to the state value and the actual DOM already has the correct value there is most likely no update and just a diff.

Comment: @JacobSmit This is what I need to know. My problem was that I used to think value attribute and event.target.value are the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

If explain it step by step - it gonna be something like this (in the context of your example) :

1. State is the reactive variable, so then it changes, your component (and nested components) rerenders. On the first render you just set it to default.
2. Then, this variable is hardly assigned to the value of an input. So in a normal situation you wouldn't be able to change the input at all, BUT.
3. You set your listener to change the state then this input gets some users interaction. Your type something - your state changes (by that time input is still empty).
4. As we already know, we changed the state. Component rerenders with new state. For example - we typed letter "T".
5. This rerender causes new state to assignee to the value of your input, you get value="T".
6. And boom - you have your new letter.

It can be said that you don't really changing the input - state does.
Hope that explanation was helpful! ;)